# Java String regex replace

Tags: java, regex

My string structure is following

characters 1-3 are uppercase alphabets including diacritics such Ň Ö Ï

Characters 4-7 will always be numbers.

8th is space

9th is forward slash

10th space

11th onwards are number.

```
String str1  = "DIW785o / 42";    // expected result "DIW7850 / 42"
String str2  = "QLR357Ï / 11";    // expected result  "QLR3571 / 11"
String str3  = "UÜÈ7477 / 00";    // expected result  "UÜÈ7477 / 00"
String str4  = "A / P8538 / 28";  //  expected result "AÏP8538 / 28"
String str5  = "CV0875Z / 01";    // expected result "CVO8752 / 01"
String str6  = "SW / 2188 / 38";  // expected result "SWÏ2188 / 38"
```

I wanted replace first 3 characters such as

```
replaceAll("[2]", "Z")
.replaceAll("[0]", "O")
.replaceAll("[5]", "S")
.replaceAll(" // ","Ï)    // replace space forward_slash space with Ï
```

and position where numbers with following

```
  .replaceAll("(?i)L|(?i)I", "1")
        .replaceAll("(?i)o", "0")
        .replaceAll("(?i)s", "5")
        .replaceAll("(?i)z", "2")
```

Comment: Can you post some examples.It's unclear as of now what you want and what u tried

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: I added input string and their expected results

Comment: Show us the string which you want to regex on it

Comment: something like `\p{Lu}` might help you with uppercase latin letters. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say its easier without regex, since you want to replace Strings, but only when they are at certain Positions:

Check, if `/` is somwere in the first 7 chars, and replace it with `Ï`:

```
if(input.indexOf(" / ") < 7 ){
    input = input.replaceFirst(" / ", "Ï");
}
```

Then all your Strings have the same length. Cut them now into the Number/Letter Part and replace everything you want:

```
String letterPart = input.substring(0,3);
String numberPart= input.substring(3,7);
String rest = input.substring(7);

letterPart = letterPart.replace("0", "O");

numberPart = numberPart.replace("o", "0");
numberPart = numberPart.replace("Ï", "1");
numberPart = numberPart.replace("Z", "2");
```

Then put everything together again:

```
String result = letterPart + numberPart + rest;
```